# Pandas sql update efficiently

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas

I am using python pandas to load data from a MySQL database, change, then update another table. There are a 100,000+ rows so the UPDATE query's take some time.

Is there a more efficient way to update the data in the database than to use the `df.iterrows()` and run an `UPDATE` query for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not pandas, it is the `UPDATE` operations. Each row will fire its own `UPDATE` query, meaning lots of overhead for the database connector to handle.

You are better off using the [`df.to_csv('filename.csv')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method for dumping your dataframe into CSV, then read that CSV file into your MySQL database using the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Load it into a new table, then `DROP` the old one and `RENAME` the new one to the old ones name.

Furthermore, I suggest you do the same when loading data into pandas. Use the [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html) MySQL command and then load that file into pandas using the [`pd.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) method.

Comment: Never even thought of doing it that way. Thanks